# Question on showing homeomorphism between spaces in Topology

Tags: general-topology

[image]The following question comes from a section in a topology text having to do with contracting subsets.  
Prove that the following spaces are homeomorphic:
(a) $\mathbb{R}^2$
(b) $\mathbb{R}^2/I$
(d) $\mathbb{R}^2/I^2$

I am uncertain if I am asked to show homeomorphsim between the plane, an unit interval and the unit square.  I did not even know it is possible that homeomorphism between any two of these three spaces.

Can someone show me how such is possible?  Thank you in advance.

[Edit:  I have edited the post to include the page where the question comes from.  I am not certain if the question preceding the one I am asking in the included page will be of relevance to the one I am asking. My apologies for the confusion]

Comment: What is $I$?  I don't think that's a standard abbreviation.

Comment: @Robert It refers to the closed unit interval in $\mathbb R$ in Hatcher. Probably a reasonable guess, but OP should clarify.

Comment: I suggest using the command `\setminus` instead of `/` as to avoid confusing the notation with that of a quotient group

Comment: You're not being asked to prove that the plane is homeomorphic either to the unit interval or the unit square.  It's not.  The plane isn't compact.  The other two spaces are.  And removing a single point from the unit interval can disconnect it, whereas that's not true of the other two spaces.  You're being asked to prove that the modification of the plane with (b) the unit interval or (c) the unit square contracted to a single point is homeomorphic to the plane.

Comment: @clathratus I think the quotient group really is what's intended by the question.

Comment: @RobertShore I'm voting to closed due to the lack of clarity

Comment: @clathratus I've seen that notation before, and if it's relatively standard, then the question really isn't unclear.

Comment: @RobertShore the question came from a topology problems text, question 22.5. Here is the link: books.google.ca/books/about/… Am I asked to show homeomorphism for three different spaces

Comment: This confirms that the quotient notation denotes contractions of the identified subsets to a single point.  So think about a plane in which the unit interval is contracted to a single point.  Or a unit square is contracted to a single point.

Comment: @RobertShore in the case of a disc, contracting to a single point would be a sphere, and same for the unit square. But the plane is not compact.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @RobertShore I don't know what you mean by modification of the plane with the unit interval.  Is it asking me to contract a unit interval to a single point, what will the plane look like afterwards?

Comment: Yes, and it's also telling you the answer (that it's not topologically different from the unaltered plane).

Comment: @RobertShore, when I am contracting an unit interval, unit disc or a unit square to a single point, does it matter which single point as an element of the space I am contracting the space to.  Meaning, say take the unit interval from [0,1], it doesn't matter if i collapse it to the point 0, 1 or 1/2.  Is that correct?

Comment: Not really.  Technically what's going on is you're considering the interval (or square) an equivalence class and any open set that includes any part of the equivalence class contains the entire equivalence class.

Comment: @RobertShore thank you for your explanation.  I have edited the post to include the original page source.  My apologies for my late reply.  I have been feeling under the weather yesterday.  
I think I am a bit confused over what you are trying to describe.  I know what it means for a space to collapse to a point. As an example, if collapsing the top part of the cylinder to a point, the resulting space is an upright circular cone.  I am not sure if this is what you are trying to describe.

Comment: You have it right.  Check out some of the other example exercises in your text (some of which seem pretty simple) to confirm your understanding.

Comment: @RobertShore thank you for all your explanations. I really appreciate you taking the time.

Comment: @SethMai The following comment of your is not correct, or not clear: "in the case of a disc, contracting to a single point would be a sphere, and same for the unit square." IF you start with a disc and IF you only contract its circumference to a point THEN you indeed get a sphere. BUT, if you contract a disc, every point of the disc, circumference and interior points, then you get a single point. So in your question,parts (bcd), you contract each (and all) of $I,D^2,I^2$ to a single point. The case of $D^2$ is easiest, if $|x|>1$ send $x$ to $x(|x|-1)$, and if $|x|\le1$ send $x$ to the origin.

Answer (score 0):

For a point $(x,y)$ in the plane let $|(x,y)|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ denote the usual Euclidean norm. 
$\def\R{\Bbb R^2}$

Part (c) of the question (as shown on the included picture by OP) asking for a homeomorphism between $\R$ and $\R/D^2$ is easiest (where $D^2$, I assume is the unit disc, $D^2=\{(x,y):|(x,y)|\le1\}$).

In this case let $h(x,y)=(0,0)$ if $|(x,y)|\le1$, and 
let $h(x,y)=(x,y)\cdot(|(x,y)|-1)$ if $|(x,y)|\ge1$. 
Note that here $(0,0)$ as an element of $\R/D^2$ is used to represent the point to which all points of $D^2$ were sent (or smashed to). So, $h:\R\to\R/D^2$, and $h$ is easily shown to be a homeomorphism. Indeed $h$ is constant on $D^2$ so (its restriction) is continuous. Also, clearly $h$ is continuous on the set $E=\{(x,y):|(x,y)|\ge1\}$. The intersection of $D^2$ and $E$ is the unit circle and the two definitions of $h$ agree on the unit circle so $h$ is continuous by the [Pasting Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasting_lemma). One has to show also that $h$ is a bijection and $h^{-1}$ is continuous ... left to the reader.

The notation $I=[0,1]$ is standard in most topology books. But, for the present purposes (for part (d) only) I prefer to use $I=[-1,1]$, (it is not really much different, but is technically easier to work with).

In case (d) we need to show that $\R$ and $\R/I^2$ are homeomorphic. It is perhaps a more common exercise to show that $D^2$ and $I^2$ are homeomorphic, 
so part (d) in this way becomes closely related to part (c). At any rate, one could exhibit a homeomorphism, using a different norm on $\R$ (the [maximum norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Maximum_norm_(special_case_of:_infinity_norm,_uniform_norm,_or_supremum_norm))), that is, let $||(x,y||=\max\{|x|,|y|\}$. Note that $I^2$ is the same as the (closed) "unit ball" with respect to this norm, i.e. $I^2=\{(x,y):||(x,y)||\le1\}$. Define a homeomorphism $g:\R\to\R/I^2$ by 
$g(x,y)=(0,0)$ if $(x,y)\in I^2$, and $g(x,y)=(x,y)\cdot(||(x,y)||-1)$ if $||(x,y)||\ge1$.

It could be shown in a similar manner that if $C$ is a compact and convex subset of $\R$, and if $C$ has a non-empty interior then $\R$ and $\R/C$ are homeomorphic. Indeed one could use $C$ to define a norm on $\R$ (but I won't go into details) and then use this norm to define a homeomorphism.

Finally consider case (b), $\R/I$. 
This time I find it more convenient to work with 
$I=[0,1]$ but since it is understood that $I\subset\R$ we must formally use $I=[0,1]\times\{0\}=$ $\{(x,0):0\le x\le1\}=$ $\{(x,y):0\le x\le1,y=0\}$. 
Note that $I$ is compact and convex, but has empty interior. 
Nevertheless one could explicitly describe a homeomorphism $f:\R\to\R/I$. (I do not know of a "standard" way to do this, but here is one description that works.)

If $|y|\ge1$ let $f(x,y)=(x,y)$.
Also, if $x\le0$ then let $f(x,y)=(x,y)$.
If $|y|\le1$ and $x\ge1$ let $f(x,y)=(x-(1-|y|),y)$.
If $|y|\le1$ and $0\le x\le1$ let $f(x,y)=(x\cdot|y|,y)$.
Again, the pasting lemma could be used to show that $f$ is continuous (and with some more work, that it is a homeomorphism $f:\R\to\R/I$.) Several cases need to be considered, but I would only verify one: when $|y|\le1=x$. Then $f(x,y)=(1-(1-|y|),y)=(|y|,y)$ and also $f(x,y)=(1\cdot|y|,y)=(|y|,y)$, so these definitions agree. (Note also that $f(1,1)=(1,1)$ whether you use the definition $f(x,y)=(x,y)$, or $f(x,y)=(x-(1-|y|),y)$, or $f(x,y)=(x\cdot|y|,y)$. )

(The following is an abandoned attempt to describe a homeomorphism $f:\R\to\R/I$, where $I=[-1,1]\times\{0\}=$ $\{(x,0):-1\le x\le1\}=$ $\{(x,y):-1\le x\le1,y=0\}$, but I changed my mind and described the above instead. If $|x|\le1$ let $f(x,0)=(0,0)$. If $|x|\ge1$ let $f(x,0)=(x\cdot(|x|-1),0)$. There are different way to deal with $|y|\neq0$. Let $f(x,y)=(x,y)$ if $|y|\ge1$. Finally, if $0\le|y|\le1$ consider two cases depending on whether $|x|\le|y|$ or $|x|\ge|y|$. If $0\le|x|\le|y|\le1$ then let ...)

Comment: Thank you again for your detail response. I am always amazed at the many member of this community of their expertise at various subtopics of undergraduate and graduate level mathematics, yourself included.

Comment: @SethMai You are welcome, and thank you!